# Linux Bash custom function not found when executed from mysql

Tags: mysql, linux, bash, ubuntu, windows-10

I am new to linux shell scripts. I have created a function **sel1** in bashrc file.

```
function sel1(){
        echo "select * from table limit 1;"
}
```

This function works as expected when called from the bash I get this output

```
akshayk@AKSHAY-PC:/$ sel1
select * from table limit 1;
```

Also I have found that we can run bash commands after mysql connection like below ls command

```
mysql> \! ls
acct  bin  boot  cache  data  dev  etc  home  init  lib  lib64  lost+found  media  mnt  opt  proc  root  run  sbin  srv  sys  tmp  usr  var
```

But when I call the function from mysql it says not found

```
mysql> \! sel1
sh: 1: sel1: not found - What could be the problem here ?
```

Also is there a way to get the output of a function at the **cursor location**?

For testing this I am using ubuntu bash on windows 10. The system where I plan to run these commands is running CentOS.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: afaik, the shell `mysql` is not aware of the function `sel1` created outside of it...
Try to execute `\! set` and search for `sel1()` in the output: if it is not there, your problem is that what you define out of the mysql shell will not be included.
Same should be for vars.

Answer (score 1):

`ls` is actually `/bin/ls`, an executable, and is defined in your PATH variable.  MySQL does not run your `.bashrc` file, so this function is unknown to it.

Modify your function into a script and make sure it's path is included in your PATH variable.

Ex: file `/home/youruser/sel1`, with executable permissions:

```
#!/bin/bash 
echo "select * from table limit 1;"
```

Put "/home/youruser" in your PATH variable.  Then you will be able to run it.

Answer (score 1):

Nic3500 did a pretty good job but let me add that the shells are processes and functions are not exported to subprocesses.  When you defined the `sel1` function, you were in the parent shell.  You started MySQL, process 2 and tried to run `sel1` by running `\!`, which produces process 3.

You can see this by viewing the shell process ID, starting MySQL and viewing the process ID again. I just tried that and got:

```
$ bash
$ function sel1 {
>     echo "select * from table limit 1;"
> }
$ sel1
select * from table limit 1;
$ export sel1
$ bash
$ sel1
bash: sel1: command not found
```

If you have a complicated function, you will need to run the script that defines the function followed by calling the function in the same `\!` invocation.

As for sending the function output to the cursor location, I take it you want to run a script that produces, say, a select at the sql prompt. For that, I think your best bet is to use a shell to produce a script that you then batch in.